# How to divide by a value in columnA that correlates to another value in ColumnB

Tags: sql

I am creating a SQL report to show the number of viles on hand, sales orders, PO etc.
My system has everything in the base units (mL), and I need to divide by the DefaultPurchasingUnit which is 11. How do I do that if this is from one table?

```
Item   UnitSize  Unit            DefaultPurchasingUnit     
====== ========  ==============  =====================
Item1  1         mL              vile
Item1  11        vile            vile
Item1  693       box             vile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `join` or window functions:

```
select t.*,
       t.unitsize / tdef.unitsize
from t left join
     t tdef
     on t.item = tdef.item and
        t.DefaultPurchasingUnit = tdef.unit;
```

Comment: I dont think I can use a left join since everything is already from the same table.

Comment: @ManuelWan: you can do a left with the table itself

Answer (score 0):

You ***can*** use a left join on the same table:

```
SELECT A.Item, A.UnitSize AS SizeInML, A.UnitSize / B.UnitSize AS DefaultUnitSize, B.Unit, B.DefaultPurchasingUnit 
FROM itemTable A 
LEFT JOIN itemTable B 
ON A.Item = B.Item AND A.DefaultPurchasingUnit = B.Unit
```

I ran this in SQL and it gave the following result where default purchasing unit for Item1 is `vile` and for Item2 is `box` with the same values as provided in your question (1, 11, 693 for mL, vile, box respectively):

```
Item   SizeInML   DefaultUnitSize   Unit     DefaultPurchasingUnit     
====== ========   ===============   =======  =====================
Item1  1          0.0909            vile     vile
Item1  11         1                 vile     vile
Item1  693        63                vile     vile
Item2  1          0.0014            box      box
Item2  11         0.0159            box      box
Item2  693        1                 box      box
```